# Mysql count() with Left Join taking over 10 seconds on 5 million records

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables that I am joining like this
I am using mysql v. 5.7

**Table: contacts** about 5 mil

id : auto inc (int) primary Key

status : Int (Index)

**Table : contact_lists** about 10 mil

id : auto inc (int) primary Key

contactId : index

listId: index

**Table: Lists** about 30

id: auto inc (int) primary key

### Here is my query , I have 10 million record on *contacts* table

```html
SELECT cl.listId, count(c.id) active from `contact_lists` cl 

LEFT JOIN `contacts` c ON c.id = cl.contactId and c.status = 1

group by cl.listId
```

Here is my Explain

```html
1   SIMPLE  cl  NULL    listId  contact_lists   8   NULL          9062524   100.00  Using index
1   SIMPLE  c   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   cl.contactId    1   100.00  Using where
```

This Query is taking over 11 seconds when I run it, any idea how can I speed it up

I have tried adding indexes nothing really worked, can I rewrite this somehow to make it faster? like less than 2 seconds, the issue is the count(c.id) is very slow when it comes to that much data

The result

```html
listId.  active
1        100
2.       3000
3.       500010
and so on
```

Comment: add the keyword `EXPLAIN` before `SELECT` and show the results. It should give you an idea where to start optimizing. Also, how many records on contact_lists?

Comment: I did can you see above, its somehow going through 9062524 and in contact_lists about 10 mil and in contacts about 5 mil

Comment: Just to make sure: your `listId`-index has to be a composite index of two columns, `(listid, contactid)` (your explain looks as if it is, but it's important enough to verify). Also, your tables need to be InnoDB (which they probably are in 5.7). If you need help verifying those points, add the `create table`-statement for your table to your question.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW INDEX FROM contact_lists; and B) SHOW INDEX FROM contacts; and C) SHOW CREATE TABLE contact_lists; and D) SHOW CREATE TABLE contacts; so we have current information.  With no WHERE, to count all of each group will require table scan.

Comment: The tables both are InnoDB and I have composite index (listid, contactid)

Comment: Even if I removed the status , it still takes 10 seconds for this query to run , I really have no idea how to speed it up

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `Explain` results, there is no index for id and status. Create those:

```
ALTER TABLE `contact`
    ADD INDEX `id_status` (`id`, `status`);
```

And you'll also need a foreign key on contact_list:

```
ALTER TABLE `contact_list`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_contact_list_contact` FOREIGN KEY (`contactId`) REFERENCES `contact` (`id`);
```

**Note that making these changes might lock your table for a little while**

Comment: I just did , it didnt do much really ? the Explain also still the same except the bottom row its using id_status, for the contraint I have that already

Comment: I just realized, there is no where clause in your query, so of course it won't be faster because it is going through every single record.

Comment: modern MySQL versions on InnoDB can execute some ALTER TABLE and CREATE iNDEX statements without locking the table search in the manual for InnoDB Online DDL

Comment: Yes so I am not sure how to make it go any faster or maybe there is no other way ?

Comment: Maybe if the status is on the list table. This way you can index id and status on the list table.

Comment: how the status will be on the list table? the status is based on per contact